# Evernote's webhook is not sending when a notebook is deleted

Tags: evernote

I'm deleting a notebook from Evernote, but my webapp is not receiving the webhook associated with this action. In theory and following the official documentation, my webapp should receive something like that:

`[base URL]/?userId=[user ID]&notebookGuid=[notebook GUID]&reason=notebook_update`

The main problem of this behavior is that the notes inside this notebook are being sending to the trash on Evernote and there is no webhook about these changes neither.

does anyone know the reason behind this problem? is there another option to be aware of this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask the Evernote support team.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any tutorial about Webhook. The document is quite  confusion. There are two options: **Request an API Key** and **Request a Webhook**. But there is another button **Get An API Key** at top right corner of website. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Looked into this - turns out we (Evernote) don't currently support webhook notifications for delete, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Had you received confirmation that your webhook was set up? Try again please?

For others, FYI: we do indeed keep an eye on questions tagged evernote on Stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks for you answers! yes, we received the confirmation by email. In fact, we are receiving webhooks for different actions, for example, create a notebook. The problem resides in the delete notebook action, in this case we are not receiving anything about this notebook and its notes.

Answer (score 0):

@akhaku thanks for your answer again! just one comment to clarify, for me the behavior is a little bit weird, because when we delete a note we are receiving something like this:

/note-integration/webhook/evernote/?userId=XXXXXXXXX&guid=YYYYYY&notebookGuid=ZZZZZ&reason=update

However, when we delete a notebook we are not receiving anything about the notebook and its notes.

From my point of view, at least we should receive webhooks about the notes  inside the notebook when the notebook has been deleted. In other case, it's impossible to identify this case.

Comment: Hi,I am also trying to implement webhook notification in my app ,as for docs i have registered webhook endpoint and got email from support team as "Endpoint updated successfully".So I have tried to get notify when Evernote gets create or update but unfortunately I am not able to get any notification.What I tried is I wrote function to listen the request for notification using http module in Node.js.
Can someone suggest me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes evernote doesn't support webhook notificatiosn as confirmed with evernote developer support for some weird reason

The only way the delete changes can be detected is through polling https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/polling_notification.php#webhooks

It needs to be implemented like the code below

```
int latestUpdateCount = ... // Persist this value

// Each time you want to check for new and updated notes...
SyncState currentState = noteStore.getSyncState();
int currentUpdateCount = currentState.getUpdateCount();

if (currentUpdateCount > latestUpdateCount) {

  // Something in the account has changed, so search for notes
  NotesMetadataList newNotes = noteStore.findNotesMetadata( ... );

  // Do something with the notes you found...
  for (NoteMetadata note : newNotes.getNotes()) {
    // ...
  }

  // Keep track of the new high-water mark
  latestUpdateCount = currentSyncState.getUpdateCount();
}
```